# page inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

Suppose I have a web project and a bunch of different Web Forms, effectively all different classes inheriting `System.Web.UI.Page`.

I decided it'd be great to have some fields, methods, and a few things to happen in the `Page_Load` method of any page I use in my project.

Off the cuff, I thought perhaps to make a class, say MasterPage, that has all the fields and methods I want (with `protected` level) and have this class inherit `System.Web.UI.Page`.

Then every page in my project should now inherit from MasterPage instead of `System.Web.UI.Page`.

While this worked, there were a couple problems with it.

1. I couldn't really "catch" forms that were still inheriting from `System.Web.UI.Page` very easily.  Is there an easy way?
2. Due to the way it was setup, the MasterPage's PageLoad is virtual and has to be overridden e.g.:

   ```
   protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       base.Page_Load(sender, e);
       // rest of stuff for this page...
   }
   ```

   Is there any easier way to have the parent's method always called first without explicitly putting in the base call in every page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find/replace is your friend.
2. Don't override an event handler in the inheriting class. Instead, make the base handler private and create new handlers in your inheriting class. Or, override [`OnInit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd6at422.aspx) in your base class so you don't have to worry about which `Page_Load` was called first.

Another completely different solution is to use [ASP.NET Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh). This is usually the best way to share content across all pages in a web application.

> Master pages provide functionality that developers have traditionally
>   created by copying existing code, text, and control elements
>   repeatedly; using framesets; using include files for common elements;
>   using ASP.NET user controls; and so on.

[image: Master page resulting page composition]

Comment: I went with the OnInit route, might try the Master thing on a different project.  Bert's answer also worked and is useful, too.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative method is to create your super class that inherits from Page and then just add it's own event handlers to the Page events.  Sometimes it's easy to forget that you can attach as many handlers as you want to an event.

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class CustomPage: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
         public CustomPage()
         {
            this.Init += new EventHandler(CustomPage_Init);
            this.Load += new EventHandler(CustomPage_Load);
            this.PreRender += new EventHandler(CustomPage_PreRender);
            this.Unload += new EventHandler(CustomPage_Unload);
         }

         protected void CustomPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            //do stuff
         } 

     ...
    }
}
```

Then in your pages, just inherit and do what you normally do, and both events will fire.

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class NewPage: CustomPage
    {
        void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do more stuff
        }
    }
}
```